# Grails - on generating views using GGTS

Tags: grails

I was running GGTS to generate the domain, controller and view. I realized that the view generation (New > Generate Views), is dependent on the domain.

I realized that the V and the M is tightly coupled. Would this be breaking the MVC rule?

A newb in Grails (using GGTS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your question is a little bit vague (what do you mean by "tightly coupled" and "MVC rule"), I don't consider that Grails views are "too coupled" with the domain layer and I definitly think you should keep generating your domain, controller and views with Grails functionality.
Here are my reasons:

- The view layer is intrinsically dependent on the domain (Model in MVC); the MVC model is something really debatable, and [here you have a fairly good discussion about it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really), but I do think that the convention that Grails implements is clean and easy to maintain;
- Grails is heavily based on [Convention over Configuration](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.2/guide/gettingStarted.html#conventionOverConfiguration) and that by itself demands the use of best practices as the mainly used convention (or else I wouldn't see much gain), and I think the guys from Grails did a really good job in that; This means that instead of ignoring it (as suggested by Chetan) I would rather study the generated code to get a better understanding of grails (and groovy) principles.

I hope to have cleared that a little bit. But if I didn't, the references I passed can do the job. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I have gone through your phase and I would suggest not to generate the code and views as you will find it way more confusing than reading documentation and writing your own code.
Secondly it will be very difficult in modifying the code in future due to its level of complexity for auto generated code.